# Чтение отдельного фрагмента файла

Tags: файлы, c++

Например есть файл размером 1 ГБ.

Как получить участок данных, находящиеся где-то посередине, не читая его полностью?

Comment: @KoVadim уже ответил, и ответ принят, но всё-таки... Что Вам хотелось бы получить? Какой файл (текст, двоичный), отсортирован или нет, как определить нужный участок? Потому как всякие fseek требуют либо ftell с предварительным чтением, либо вычисления нужного места с учётом структуры файла.

Comment: файл бинарный или текстовый не важно. мне нужно найти в нем данные по  указанному размеру от начала файла например 12 байт и длиной 24 байта от начала искомых данных.

Comment: Разница в том, что в текстовом файле можно начать чтение в произвольной позиции, найти перевод строки, и Вы получите начало следующей. В бинарном не исключён вариант, что начало блока найти невозможно. А может и наоборот -- проще. Так что ситуация та же -- исходных данных мало.

Comment: давайте рассмотрим два варианта примем вариант @KoVadim как вариант с текстовым файлом. Пусть кто нибудь напишет (может быть даже вы это сделаете) вариант с бинарным файлом (условие остается прежнее).

Comment: @perfect, для `fseek()` (C++ `seekg()`) никакой разницы между текстовым и бинарным файлами не существует.

В мире \*nix ее вообще нет. Эти файлы только в голове программиста в чем-то различаются.

В винде, действительно, есть различия на уровне преобразования данных при чтении-записи. 

При чтении текстового файла, символ Ctrl-Z воспринимается как конец файла, а последовательность из 2-х символов `"\r\n"` заменяется одним `'\n'`.

При записи текстового файла каждый символ `'\n'` заменяется  на последовательность `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @avp я согласен с вами, просто меня смутил комментарий @alexlz не стал оспаривать его точку зрения потому что вдруг я чего то не знаю

Comment: @avp ну как бы сейчас -- да. Раньше было смешнее (см. типы/форматы файлов в RMS-11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Использовать функции семейства `*seek`. Если используете старый, сишный способ чтения файлов (`fopen`, 'fread`), тогда используйте функцию [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/). Эта функция получает три параметра  - первый - файловый дескриптор, третий - способ "перемотки" - от начала, от текущей позиции или от конца. А второй параметр указывает на сколько байт "перематывать". Также парная к ней функция [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/), которая возвращает текущее положение.

Если используете работу через stream (fstream), тогда нужна функция [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/).

Comment: она из стандартной библиотеке с++?

Comment: Да. Стандартней некуда:)