# Самый быстрый метод обработки строк в файле, чтение запись c++

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, csv

Есть форматированная строка `abc / 123.456, 456.789, 321.654`. Количество пробелов может варьироваться.

Есть файл, в нем более 100 000  таких строк.

Как **быстро** пробежаться по файлу и на выходе получить другой файл, с изменённым форматом строки
`text 123.456 456.789 321.654`?

**Совершенно верно Harry `Пока ваша задача выглядит как считать строку, все до первого числа заменить на text, и убрать запятые`**

P.s.
Делал программу "конвертер" на vb, работает медленно, через регулярные выражения. Парсит, делает математические действия с числами, в результате обрабатывает 70 000 строк более 5 минут, компьютер фактически не загружен, на 10% загружен центральный процессор, оперативная память практически не расходуется.

P.p.s. начал изучать c++ и столкнулся с множеством путей решения, подскажите пожалуйста более грамотный.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230822/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: Посмотрите на [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) для Линукс или [File Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx) для винды.

Comment: Вы бы как-то поточнее пояснили, что надо сделать... Пока ваша задача выглядит как считать строку, все до первого числа заменить на `text`, и убрать запятые. Если так - то запросто, можно набросать вам код сразу. Так что дайте более точное описание, что именно вам надо. А то, как говорится, без точного ТЗ результат ХЗ...

Comment: @avp По-моему, проблема в выбранном алгоритме работы, и FileMapping тут никак не спасет.

Comment: **Совершенно верно** @Harry 'Пока ваша задача выглядит как считать строку, все до первого числа заменить на text, и убрать запятые'

Comment: Числа все положительные? или с `-` могут начинаться?

Comment: @Harry Числа могут иметь разные знаки, могут начинаться с `-`

Comment: @Harry, по сути ТС спрашивает, как быстрее всего работать с файлом. Быстрее всего (по крайней мере читать) прямо из файлового кэша, получая его отображение в свое адресное пространство. В данном случае (imho) проще всего mmap только читать, а результат выводить  в другой файл (сделав размер буфера побольше), а потом просто мувнуть результат в исходный файл.

Comment: @avp Я бы сказал - не как быстро **читать**, а как быстро **решить всю задачу** преобразования...

Comment: @Harry, Вы же сами написали в комментарии. Найти `/`, вывести слово `"text "`, скопировать остаток строки на выход (тут надо экспериментировать, что быстрее fwrite (2 прохода, один раз сами ищем `\n`, второй копирование символов внутри fwrite) или putc (которая м.б. **макро**) в цикле).

Comment: @avp Для начала достаточно отказаться от регулярных выражений, к которым прибег ТС :)

Comment: @Harry, это естественно. Собственно, как я думаю, нас-то сама задача ТС уже не интересует... В принципе же, в текущей постановке (чуть внимательней посмотрел на данные) это задача копирования символов в том же буфере (т.е. результат будет иметь меньший размер, чем исходный файл) с заменой (сначала по месту, потом пишем ближе к началу) и пропуском `,`. Поэтому mmap на read/write, копирование и truncate в конце должны решать ее наиболее быстро.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harry 1-й вариант (0.40 с) тормозит `out << endl;` (flush), с заменой на `out << "\n";` - 0.20 с.
Если возможно, такой вариант: float& - 0.33с, char* - 0.17c., может удобнее будет:

```
#include "stdio.h"
void main()
{
    FILE *in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    float a, b, c;
    while (fscanf(in, "abc /%f,%f,%f\n", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
        fprintf(out, "text %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f\n", a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: Да, endl->\n существенно ускоряет. Вобщем, оптимизировать можно до бесконечности :) Но, думаю, главное, что уже пошли субсекундные времена, а не 5 минут :)

Comment: @IronZeshadow - [fscanf](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf), [fprintf](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Править тут можно слишком много, вот я уже в 1 строчку вместил)

Comment: @J. Doe если использовать буфер, то будет ли прирост производительности?

`#include "stdio.h"
void main()
{
    FILE *in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    float a, b, c;
 char buf[1024];
  while(fgets(buf,1024,in)){
    while (fscanf(in, "abc /%f,%f,%f\n", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
        fprintf(out, "text %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f\n", a, b, c);
}
}

Comment: Решение плохо тем, что начинает **КОНВЕРТИРОВАТЬ** числа, в то время как задача - просто убрать запятые. Зачем эта лишняя работа?... Кстати, там, где мой вариант дает 0.1с, ваш работает 0.2с - из-за преобразования чисел. Ну и - моему плевать, что написано ДО чисел, вашему - нет, ему надо `abc /` в обязательном порядке...

Comment: @Harry, полностью с вами согласен, ваше решение более быстрое, нетривиальное,  сразу видно человек знает предмет :-)

Comment: @Harry,  решение J. Doe делает все влоб,  оно более компактное и легче читается. В моём случае убрать запятые и abc, это лишь одна из задач, которые мне нужно решить, к ним относятся математические операции с числами, в том числе и их конвертация, т.е. уменьшение количество знаков после запятой, и т.д. и т.д. и т.д.

Comment: Ну так ставьте задачу **точно**

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если минусов в начальном тексте нет, то что-то такое

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    string s;
    while(getline(in,s))
    {
        out << "text ";
        size_t pos = s.find_first_of("-0123456789");
        for(int i = pos, e = s.length(); i < e; ++i )
        {
            if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == ',')
            {
                while(s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == ',') ++i;
                out << ' ';
            }
            out << s[i] ;
        }
        out << endl;
    }
}
```

отработало на тестовом файле из 70000 строк на моей машине за примерно 0.4 секунды.

В качестве эксперимента сделан второй вариант -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE * in  = fopen("input.txt","rt");
    FILE * out = fopen("output.txt","wt");
    char buf[1024];
    while(fgets(buf,1024,in))
    {
        fputs("text ",out);
        char * s = strpbrk(buf,"-0123456789");
        for(; *s; ++s )
        {
            if (*s == ' ' || *s == ',')
            {
                while(*s == ' ' || *s == ',') ++s;
                fputc(' ',out);
            }
            fputc(*s,out);
        }
    }
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
}
```

Обе скомпилированы Visual C++ 2015 64bit.

Тестовый файл - 70000 строк. Усреднение времени работы по 10 запускам.
Первый вариант - 0.34с, второй - 0.10с.

Но! Заменим `string` на работу со строками в стиле C:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    char buf[1024];
    while(in.getline(buf,1024))
    {
        out << "text ";
        const char * s = strpbrk(buf,"-0123456789");
        for(; *s; ++s )
        {
            if (*s == ' ' || *s == ',')
            {
                while(*s == ' ' || *s == ',') ++s;
                out.write(" ",1);
            }
            out.write(s,1);
        }
        out.write("\n",1);
    }
}
```

Здесь время работы при тех же условиях - 0.19с.

Выводы делайте сами :)

Comment: @Abyx Смотря что вы под этим понимаете. Не думаю, что потребуется обрабатывать такие файлы сотнями, так что секундное время работы вряд ли можно считать медленным :)

Comment: @Abyx - не транслируйте городские легенды.

Comment: @Abyx Впрочем, см. результаты эксперимента :)

Comment: Можно еще попробовать добавить вызов `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Вот уж ничего не дает даже при работе с `cin`/`cout`, а уж при работе с файлами - и подавно...

Comment: @Harry, сам не проверял, но [в этом посте](https://habrahabr.ru/post/246257/) автор утверждает обратное

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Я проверял... Чтобы не быть голословным. Итак, первая программа - 0.34. Добавляю эту хреновину, - 0.34. Теперь заменяю `out` на `cout`, - тут дождаться 70000 строк нереально... Ограничусь 1000 строками - 1.96 с. Добавление этой строки - 1.97с. Так что, по крайней мере в отношении Visual C++, я в это не верю - так как экспериментально убедился, что это ничего не дает. Может, лет 15 назад что-то было иначе :), но сейчас это узкое и никак не расширяемое место в VC++...